# Sum values across a row if they are in certain columns, and if adjacent cells have a specific value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

Link to data screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rYKB.jpg

I am working with an excel file that has a recurring group of 4 columns (see image: column headers are Time, Med1, Med2, Med3). On the left, in column B, I want to have the sum of the values on a row, but the only values that should be summed are those that meet the criteria:

1. The value is in a Med1 column (all columns that have the Med1 header), and;
2. The adjacent Time value on the same row (1 column to the left of a Med1 column) is 1.5 or greater.

So, for example looking at row 10 (highlighted in the example), the Med1 values in E10 and I10 should be summed in B10 (because their respective Time values in D10 and H10 are 1.75 and 1.5, respectively, i.e. >=1.5), but not the Med1 value in M10 (Time value in L10 is 1.25 which does not meet the second criterion above).

Some additional info:
Each of these ‘blocks’ has a fixed width of 4 columns, without gaps in between (in the actual excel file, there are 240 of these blocks). 
The pattern of Time continues like in the example shown, always starts at 0, one row lower compared to the previous block.

What I have tried: SUMIF, SUMIFS and INDEX functions, but I get #VALUE errors if I try to combine criteria (especially as it is not 1 Time column value that needs to be checked for a row, but multiple Time column values across a row).

Previously, I just wanted to sum all Med1 value on a row (regardless of the adjacent Time value), like this:

=SUMIF($D$2:$O$2;"Med1";D3:O3)

However, with the second criterion of the adjacent Time value, I cannot seem to get it to work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the blocks are all right next to each as shown in your image, and the value you want to sum is always 1 cell to the right of the time value, and only the time values can be >= 1.5 (all of your MedX values are < 1), then this formula would work for you:

```
=SUMIF(D3:O3,">=1.5",E3:P3)
```

If it's possible for the MedX values to be >= 1.5, then this more explicit formula should work for you:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($D$2:$O$2="Time"),--(D3:O3>=1.5),--($E$2:$P$2="Med1"),E3:P3)
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. I understand how 'shifting' the range works out (as the relative location of Time and Med1 are always the same), and I also have it working in case I want to sum Med2 or Med3 instead of Med1.